# How to release multiple dependent android librarys with consistent versioning?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

Given a multi module gradle project consisting of:

- app
- library A
- library B
- library C

Where

- app has dependencies on A,B,C
- B has dependencies on A
- C has dependencies on A
- A has no dependencies

How do you configure your dependencies to perform a maven release to a maven repository (i.e. uploadArchives) so that all artifacts (the app and libraries A,B and C) are released with the same version and dependent on the same version of the corresponding libraries?

For example:

To start with, the dependencies look like this

APP

```
compile project(':A')
compile project(':B')
compile project(':C')
```

B

```
compile project(':A')
```

C

```
compile project(':A')
```

This guarantees that when I build the project all libraries and app are compiled using the current codebase.

What I want to do is update one property in gradle.properties, and have all the artifacts released with that version, have dependencies on that version, and still be built using the current codebase (because the current codebase will be that version)

gradle.properties

```
PROJECT_VERSION=1.2.0
```

Ultimately I want the released versions to look like this:

APP

```
compile ('com.my.groupid:A:1.2.0')
compile ('com.my.groupid:B:1.2.0')
compile ('com.my.groupid:C:1.2.0')
```

B

```
compile ('com.my.groupid:A:1.2.0')
```

C

```
compile ('com.my.groupid:A:1.2.0')
```

What is the correct approach to achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use somenthing like this.

APP

```
compile project(':A')
compile project(':B')
compile project(':C')
```

B

```
compile project(':A')
```

C

```
compile project(':A')
```

In top-level `build.gradle` use:

```
ext{
    VERSION_NAME = 1.1.2
}
```

Then in your update script use:

```
afterEvaluate { project ->
    uploadArchives {
        repositories {
            mavenDeployer {
                beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> signing.signPom(deployment) }

                pom.groupId = GROUP
                pom.artifactId = POM_ARTIFACT_ID
                pom.version = rootProject.ext.VERSION_NAME

                //....other parts
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Define a task like:

```
task uploadAllArchives {
    description 'Upload all modules to Maven Repository'
    println ''
    println '---------------------------------'
    println 'Version: ' + version
    println 'UPLOAD ALL ARCHIVES'
    println '---------------------------------'
    println ''
    doLast{
        println ''
        println '---------------------------------'
        println 'Version: ' + version
        println 'UPLOAD ALL ARCHIVES FINISHED'
        println '---------------------------------'
        println ''
    }
}
uploadAllArchives.dependsOn(
        ':libraryA:uploadArchives',
        ':libraryB:uploadArchives',
        ':libraryC:uploadArchives')
```

Comment: I am doing something similar to this, but the problem I am seeing is that the dependencies listed in the pom that is generated for library B, for example, contain a dependency that looks like this: <dependency><groupId>mygroupid</groupId><artifactId>libraryA</artifactId><version>unspecified</version><scope>compile</scope></dependency>

Comment: Check if you are assigning the version number to pom.
Otherwise you can specify inside the `module/build.gradle` something like ` defaultConfig { versionName rootProject.ext.VERSION_NAME }`

Comment: What is the distinction you mean between the top level build.gradle and the update script? Are you suggesting I can have only one 'uploadArchives' block in the top level build file?

Comment: Usually the update script is separated from the module/build.gradle script.

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused about what you are calling my 'update script'. Are you referring to the top level build.gradle ? I am not clear on where you intend the 'afterEvaluate' block to be placed.

Comment: Check this script. https://github.com/square/leakcanary/blob/master/gradle/gradle-mvn-push.gradle